# NIDropDown menu Query

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu

I am using NIDropworn in a strip of view the problem is the drop-down table is coming over another view which I have just placed below the drop-down view.

I am unable to select and and do any operation on the drop down table .

Is there a way that I can add the drop-down in the second view.
now the dropdown is coming on the small strip of view.

For example: I am having the dropDown menu in the header of a page which is view1.and the dropdown table is coming on the body which is view2.

Comment: not getting it what exactly is your requirement here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have added the `NIDropDown` in your view.

```
    - (IBAction)btn_click:(id)sender {
    NSArray * arr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"None",@"Name",@"Date",nil];
//    NSArray * arrImage = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    if(dropDown == nil) {
        CGFloat f = 130;
        dropDown = [[NIDropDown alloc]showDropDown:sender :&f :arr :nil :@"down"];
        dropDown.delegate = self;
        dropDown.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [self.viewBelowDD addSubview:dropDown];   // may be missing this line
        [self.viewBelowDD bringSubviewToFront:dropDown];
    }
    else {
        [dropDown hideDropDown:sender];
        [self rel];
    }

}
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: @Ranbijay - Glad to help! Please accept it as your answer if it helped.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! (Y)

Comment: Hi ,I have tried with NIDropDown ,  
list is display but touch method "niDropDownDelegateMethod" is not called 

Note :I have set delegate there,at the top for dropdown object .